# Unable to inject AutoWired Enviroment when using Spring Boot 1.4 testing annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am running my Integration Tests on a Spring Boot application using Cucumber and in my step definitions, my code had been bootstrapping the Spring Boot app using this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
@Slf4j
public class CreditCardStepdefs {

....

}
```

Now, I'm trying to refactor my code to make use of the [simplified annotations](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) in Spring Boot 1.4 and the same piece of code looks like this now:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@Slf4j
public class CreditCardStepdefs {

...

}
```

However, I'm facing some problems in picking up environment variables in this particular piece of code:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Before("@RUN, @POST")
public void setUp() {
    this.host = env.getProperty("test.url") + env.getProperty("server.contextPath");
    this.results = new HashMap<>();
    this.paramKeyList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.retry = false;
    this.isPassed = true;
}
```

When I run the test, "env.getProperty()" would always throw an NPE. It seems that @AutoWired for Environment doesn't work anymore using the annotations above. What do I need to do in order to get the Environment injected into the context?

Comment: That must definitely work. Is it an apple and apple comparison though? Did you have these `@Before("@RUN, @POST")` before? I never saw this by the way: maybe the context isn't available when that code runs.

Comment: Yes all the Cucumber step defs are exactly the same. I just changed the annotations as is... really wondering what's the problem here

Comment: Where is the Cucumber setup in your code sample though?